# Import Google Scholar publications into LinkedIn publications

Tags: google-apps, research, linkedin

I am looking for a program, browser extension or userscript that can import my Google Scholar publications into my LinkedIn publications. The import could be done either on request (e.g. click) or automatically whenever I start the browser / start the computer / etc. Ideally it would allow me to ignore some publications.

Any price, OS, license and browser is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this exactly solves your problem, but a lot of bio/med researchers seem to be using a chrome extension that  allows you to import a publication from a DOI or pubmed ID: https://www.biostars.org/p/155880/